# Restrict to commit file in checked-out state in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I have two branches say dev and rel. If I am changing file 'A' under dev and without commiting I will mergr to rel, I am getting change status as "[merge]". And If change the file, commit it in dev and then merge to rel status will be "[merge,edit]". 
Is there is any option in VS 2013 where it should not allow to merge the file for developers if it is in checked-out state.

Scenario:
One file already committed to the server with change and second file is in checked out mode and not checked-in to the server.

So first file merged separately which got merged and then after changing the second file, added first and second file in single change set with checked out mode of second file. So no conflicts while merging because second file code was in checked out mode..

How to go ahead where - Developer cannot merge if file is in edit mode.. it should allow only when changes are checked in to server.

Comment: Sorry, not totally got your point, did you mean you want to disable the auto merge or not allow users merge files when the files be checked out?

Comment: Not allowing users if the files is in checked-out state.

Comment: If so, this is impossible for now. We do not have this kind of build-in feature for local workspace. If you are using server workspace, you could try to sue **Check-out lock** for target branch, a check-out lock prevents users who are using server workspaces from checking out and making changes to the locked item in their workspaces. You cannot apply a check-out lock to an item for which any pending changes exist, in any workspace other than your own. More details take a look at this link:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/understand-lock-types?view=vsts#check-out-lock

Answer (score 0):

No this isn't possible. The ability to edit files during merge is required in order to be able to perform conflict resolution.

Answer (score 0):

In TFS, merge specifically means that its this revision contains the merge from a another branch. however,merge only represent the merge operation. So it shows **[merge]** status for the unchanged file and shows **[merge,edit]** status for the files that actually changed and shows **[merge branch]** for the new add item.

It's not possible to restrict users to do the merge files when the files be checked out. This is used to resolve the conflicts.

We do not have this kind of build-in feature for local workspace. If you are using server workspace, you could try to sue **Check-out lock** for target branch, a check-out lock prevents users who are using server workspaces from checking out and making changes to the locked item in their workspaces. You cannot apply a check-out lock to an item for which any pending changes exist, in any workspace other than your own. More details take a look at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/understand-lock-types?view=vsts#check-out-lock).